# Including local package in webpack build (turborepo)

Tags: next.js, turborepo

I have two packages `ui` and `app` in a "monorepo" using turborepo.

I have the ui repo with `.tsx` files and it's not being built, it's `package.json` `main` is a typescript file.

However when running `nextjs` I get an error at the import from the `ui` main file.

Is it possible to include this `node_module` from `nextjs` perspective? When looking at `config.module.rule` I can't find any rules for typescript files. I'm not sure how typescript config for nextjs files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The turbo-repo example is using `next-transpile-modules` in the apps to get Next to transpile these package dependencies that do not have a build step:

```
// in next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["ui"]);

module.exports = withTM({
  reactStrictMode: true,
});
```

From [this article](https://turborepo.com/posts/you-might-not-need-typescript-project-references) by the creator of Turbo Repo, Jared Palmer:

> [To] do this, this package can then be used without project references or a TypeScript build step (either via tsc or esbuild etc) as long as you adhere to 2 rules:
>
> 1. The consuming application of an internal package must transpile and typecheck it.
> 2. You should never publish an internal package to NPM.
>    ...
>
> **Next.js
>
> If you use Next.js, you can satisfy these constraints with the next-transpile-modules plugin which will tell Next.js to run certain dependencies through its Webpack/Babel/TypeScript pipelines.

So make sure you're meeting the constraints outlined in the previous excerpt.  Since you're using Next, check your `next.config.js` and confirm that you're using `next-transpile-modules` for your internal dependencies.

Comment: If the app that wants to use the internal package is not a nextjs app, but just e.g. an express app or other nodejs application, how can you do transpiling?

Answer (score 3):

add this to your app's package.json should resolve it:

```json
"bundledDependencies": [
  "ui"
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the default project of Turborepo as it is explained here:  [Getting Started](https://turborepo.org/docs/getting-started). The repository itself can be found here: [GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/turborepo/tree/main/examples/basic).

This project comes with 3 different packages and two plain NextJS apps (docs/web) that use a (Button-)component from the UI repository.
Use this project to understand the structure of a Turborepo and adjust it to your needs.

I did exactly what I described above and my NextJs apps just work fine sharing (tsx-)components from the UI package.

Comment: Are you able to import packages from another package (not app)

Answer (score 2):

Since Next.js 13, you can just do the following:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  transpilePackages: ['ui'],
}
```

[Next.js doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/compiler#module-transpilation)